# Laravel - Error: 500. Update record with Ajax

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

In **Laravel 5.5**,

I want to update a row using ajax in `vanilla js`. I have an error, `500 (internal server error)`. Is it due to the `CSRF` token? If so, how do I add it to send for the update?

Below are the codes;

```
// I have an object that stores:
params = {
    method: "PUT", 
    _token: "uq1Ipn0ehw9Ias5vsgy1pT3ckq4OhdmNMqmpGu20", 
    account: "my account", 
    username: "user1"
}

let data = '';
//params._method = "PUT";
//params._token = document.getElementsByTagName('input').item(name="_token").value;

for(let property in params){
    data += property + '=' + params[property] + '&'; 
}

data = data.slice(0, -1);

console.log(data);
// _method=PUT&_token=uq1Ipn0ehw9Ias5vsgy1pT3ckq4OhdmNMqmpGu20
// &account=my account&username=user1

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/personals/' + this.value, true);
// this.value will give the id of the row that will be update.eg. 1  
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.onload = function(){
  console.log(this.responseText);
}

xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: 500 error means the error is in your Laravel application. Check the logs to find out what happened.

Comment: Indeed, check the L5 error log file. Another thing: you add the values to the URL and use a POST. You mix 2 possible request methods in one: you prepare a GET (where the token is not needed) and then POST it.

Comment: @Jeff I found out that on my update method on the controller, I have `dd($request)` but when I change it to `var_dump($request)`, it works fine. Why can't I use the `dd()` function?

Comment: @Khairul dd stands for dump and die. Calling die during an Ajax request instead of returning a response would show an error on the front end